# Ember Data DS.Model's set function does not work?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember Data, after I declare a model and commit to the store, I then retrieve it and try to set a new value for a particular field, however it is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: <DS.StateManager:ember227> could not respond to event setProperty in state rootState.loaded.created.inFlight.
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.sendRecursively ember-latest.min.js:17
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.sendRecursively ember-latest.min.js:17
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.sendRecursively ember-latest.min.js:17
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.sendRecursively ember-latest.min.js:17
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.sendRecursively ember-latest.min.js:17
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.send ember-latest.min.js:17
DS.Model.Ember.Object.extend.send ember-data.js:2540
DS.Model.Ember.Object.extend.setProperty ember-data.js:2549
(anonymous function) ember-data.js:2682
n.set ember-latest.min.js:14
c ember-latest.min.js:14
Ember.Observable.Ember.Mixin.create.set ember-latest.min.js:15
(anonymous function)
```

Details (mostly boilerplate code):

```
/* create store */
 App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 2,
    // adapter: DS.LocalStorageAdaptor.create({}),
    adapter: DS.DjangoTastypieAdapter.create({
      serverDomain:  "http://localhost:8000",
      tastypieApiUrl: 'api/v1/',
    });
});

// declare model
App.StyleData = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    storageID: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0, key: 'storageID'}),

    didCreate: function(){
        // console.log('didcreate');
    },

});

/*create new model */

App.store.createRecord(App.StyleData, {storageID: 0});
App.store.commit();

/* retrieve model and set new value for storageID */
var mod = App.store.findAll( App.StyleData );
var mod1  = mod.get('modelCache')[0];
mod1.set('storageID', 10)     // here the error above is thrown
```

Comment: I think u may be trying to set before the data is complete loaded, try using observer as in my answer, not sure if it's the right solution or you could just write a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var update = function(){
  if(mod.isLoaded()){
    mod1.set('storageID', 10);
  }
}.observes('mod.isLoaded')
```

Comment: Perhaps there is also a `didLoad` handler on the model to do the same thing ?

Comment: not sure about the "didLoad" but I use "isLoaded" in my projects & it works pretty fine though...

Comment: I tried something with didLoad, but does'nt work. +1 for you :)

Answer (score 3):

This error comes from attempting to modify a record while it is being saved via API call. In your example, `App.store.commit()` initiates an ajax operation to send the details of the new record to your API. Ajax calls are asynchronous operations, so the record enters the `inFlight` state until the API responds and ember-data will transition the record back to `clean` if everything is successful. While it is `inFlight`, it may not be modified.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, could you provide a solution to work around that ?

Comment: You could override RESTAdapter to call didCreateRecord(...) immediately instead of waiting for the ajax call to complete. This has risks associated with it -- if your ajax call fails, your app and server are out of sync.

Comment: Ok, indeed, not it's a very good idea, it seems the solution from @Unspecified works fine for those cases.